# I am trying to use fullpage-vue on nuxt 3 but its not working for me

Tags: nuxt.js, fullpage.js

```
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-swiper',
    '@nuxt/image',
    '@fullpage/nuxt-fullpage',
  ],
```

I have installed it and that's how I linked it to my 'nuxt.config.js'

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <full-page
    :options="{
          licenseKey: null,
          css3: true,
          menu: '#navigation',
          anchors: ['home', 'services', 'pictures', 'prices', 'contact'],
        }"
    >
      <div  id="section">
        <div data-anchor="home">
          <HomeBanner />
        </div>

        <div data-anchor="services">
          <HomeProductsTabsComponent/>
        </div>

        <div data-anchor="pictures">
          <Experience/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </full-page>
  </div>
 
</template>
```

that's how i am using it but there's no section is displaying on my page

Comment: Any errors/warnings in the console? Have you set a license? https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/pricing/

Comment: no errors. Is it paid ?

Comment: Check the plugin page, there are indeed some specific license needs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the official [Nuxt module for fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/nuxt-fullpage)